# How possible that to generate QR Code in ionic 5

Tags: html, angular, ionic4

Is there any possible method to generate QR Code in Ionic 5? I have tried but it keep says that `qrcode` is not known element.

This is my code

`qrcode.html`

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="My QR data" [(ngModel)]="myAngularxQrCode"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-card *ngIf="createdCode">
    <qrcode [qrdata]="'myAngularxQrCode'"></qrcode>
    <ion-card-content>
        <p>Value: {{qrData}}</p>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

`qrcode.ts`

```
export class qrcode implements OnInit {
    createdCode = null;
    myAngularxQrCode = null;
    qrData = 'http://hrms.my-epmo.com/default.aspx';

    constructor() {
        this.myAngularxQrCode = 'Your QR code data string';
    }
}
```

This is what i have tried. I hope someone can help me solve this problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you import in AppModule? https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-qrcode#basic-usage

Comment: @Beller yes i already import it. but still that error come up

Comment: I have made a stackblitz sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-s9uw4k

Answer (score 1):

My app.module.ts looks like:

```
//imports....
import { QRCodeModule } from 'angularx-qrcode';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    QRCodeModule,
    .....
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    .....
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My home.component.html looks like:

```
<ion-content padding>
   <ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="My QR data" [(ngModel)]="myAngularxQrCode"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-card >
      <qrcode [qrdata]="myAngularxQrCode"></qrcode>
      <ion-card-content>
      <p>Value: {{myAngularxQrCode}}</p>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: okay, I have removed `*ngIf="createdCode"` from my code. and the error is gone. but there is no QR Code generated

Comment: Yes, you have set it like createdCode = null; But I didn't know that it will change or not... so I simply removed..

Answer (score 1):

I've used ngx-qrcode.

In your template

```
<ngx-qrcode [qrc-value]="createdCode">
  </ngx-qrcode>
```

In your controller

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.globals.access.user;
    this.createCode(this.globals.access.user.username);
  }


  createCode(toEncode) {
    this.createdCode = toEncode;
  }
```

Comment: still did not resolve my problem. It says undefined

Comment: What Is undefined?

Comment: that `toEncode`. but its okay right now. I've solve the problem.

its supposed to be `<ngx-qrcode [value]="createdCode"></ngx-qrcode>`