# How can i genereate qrcode that generate image in ionic angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, qr-code

how can i generate QrCode in ionic angular that generate image that store data. for example, when user booking slot, they will get the QrCode . if the staff scan QrCode it will display image that hold the booking data. can someone help me.

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61946804/how-possible-that-to-generate-qr-code-in-ionic-5 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for generate that. set your text to [value] attr.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@techiediaries/ngx-qrcode